# Issue with Tabs setSwipeActivated.

Tags: tabs, codenameone

I have a Tabs container in my form with 2 tabs. The first tab has a list and when a list item is clicked the second tab is scrolled to using setSelectedIndex. At first the tabs are not scrollable. However when the second tab is swiped to. I want the tabs to become scrollable in order to allow the user to go back using the swipe gesture. So I set the swipeActivated to false initially and then when the list item is clicked I try to setSwipeActivated to true and then revalidate the form however this does not activate the swipe gesture when I run the app. Here is my code.

Called as the app is opened:

```
public void setUpMainPage() {
    mainForm = (Form) u.createContainer(theme, "MainPage");
    Tabs mainTabs = (Tabs) u.findByName("MainTabs", mainForm);
    mainTabs.setAnimateTabSelection(false);
    mainTabs.setSwipeActivated(false);
    findContainer = (Container) u.findByName("GridContainer",     
mainForm);

    setUpFindContainer();
    setUpMibrand();
    setUpVouchers();
    setUpHomePage();

    findTabs = (Tabs) u.findByName("FindTabs", mainForm);
    findTabs.hideTabs();
    findTabs.setSwipeActivated(false);

    insideTabs = (Tabs) u.findByName("InsideTabs", mainForm);
    insideTabs.hideTabs();
    insideTabs.setSwipeActivated(false);

    homeTabs = (Tabs) u.findByName("HomeTabs", mainForm);
    homeTabs.hideTabs();
    homeTabs.setSwipeActivated(false);

    mainForm.show();
}
```

The ActionListener for the list items:

```
class findActionListener implements ActionListener {

    String[] categoryList = {"Shopping Malls", "Food & Dining", "Clothing & Accessories", "Grocery Stores",
        "Nightlife & Drinks", "Electronics", "Fitness & Health", "Travel & Hotels",
        "Activities & Events", "Sports Gear", "House & Home", "Baby & Kids", "Beauty & Spa", "Motoring", "Liquor Stores", "More"};

    int index;
    Label categoryLabel;
    public findActionListener(int i, Label catLabel) {
        index = i;
        categoryLabel = catLabel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        findTabs.setSelectedIndex(1, true);
        //I set the swipe activated to true on click. Before I switch
        //tabs
        findTabs.setSwipeActivated(true);
        categoryLabel.setText(categoryList[index]);
        setUpFindList(categoryList[index]);
        mainForm.revalidate();
    }

}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is what I want to achieve not possible?

Comment: If you don't toggle the swipeActivated does it work? When you say scrollable are you refering to swipeable? Notice that scrolling and tab swipe are completely separate actions! Make sure the Tabs are in the center of a border layout within the parent form so they take up the right size in a non-scrollable parent.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I am talking about making the tabs swipeable. When I toggle it in my setUpMainPage() it does swipe. The problem I am having is preventing the swipe initially and only activate it once a list item is clicked and the selectedIndex changes. So I will constantly need to be toggling and untoggling the swipeActivated.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Strangely enough. When I open a Dialog and then dispose of that dialog the tabs are able to swipe. So if I just call tabs.setSwipeActivated(true) and revalidate the form the tabs aren't able to swipe. However when I call setSwipeActivated(true) and then directly below that I show an empty dialog and then dispose of it the tabs are suddenly able to swipe. What is called when I create, show and dispose of a dialog that is triggering the setSwipeActivated. So that I can call that instead of creating a pointless dialog. For obvious reasons.

Comment: Try using forceRevalidate on the form and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check that swipeActivated is unchecked in the GUI builder UI for the tabs.

Also make sure that any code where you invoke setSwipeActivated true isn't reached.

Comment: There is no swipeActivated checkbox in the GUI Builder. Are you talking about scrollable x?

Comment: Scrolling of any type shouldn't be activated for any of the tabs or any of its parents. Did you place breakpoints on your calls to setSwipeActivated?